# Get the value of a string which is inside () in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

In a text file I have content

```
build.setDisplayName(revisionNumber)
```

I need to read the content of a file and get the value which is inside `()`.

I have tried the below but no use

```
Select-String -Path "$PSScriptRoot/text.txt" -Pattern '(.*)?'

Select-String -Path "$PSScriptRoot/text.txt" -Pattern "(?:)".Matches.Value
```

**Note**: Assume we don't know what is the string inside ().
My expected output is `revisionNumber`

Comment: Your regular expression (`(.*)?`) matches `(revisionNumber)`, so you need some time to read the help from Select-String [about_Regular_Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3) .   Secondly, the `Select-String` returns a MatchInfo object, so this will get you closer to your desired result: `(Select-String -Path "$PSScriptRoot/text.txt" -Pattern '\(.*\)').Matches.Value` (it will return: `(revisionNumber)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex `(` and `)` are special characters so you must escape them if you want to match literal parentheses

```
(Select-String -Path "$PSScriptRoot/text.txt" -Pattern '\(.*\)').Matches.Value
```

If you want to exclude the parentheses then use this

```
(Select-String  -Path "$PSScriptRoot/text.txt" -Pattern '\((.*)\)').Matches.Groups[1].Value
```